# Seeking title of sci fi book with 'bee camera' global paparazzi

Tags: story-identification

Media use bee-like paparazzi cameras, one character works at a consumer research firm that uses virtual reality Matrix-style plugging into people’s heads to survey their opinions on products; this character is younger (or small), maybe named Tag? Trig? Trip? He lives in a group-home type of situation where everyone pitches in some money/currency into a box in the house (like a coin box). Some random guy on the roof in a garden shed who has special powers, can’t touch or be touched, something like that. I think the book has a key event at a ball game or stadium involving the guy from the roof? Book may or may not also have nano-viruses in the world where cities are shielded from particular nano-viruses (I might be mixing this up with something else)

Comment: You should probably split this up into two questions, unless you think that the books are part of the same series.

Comment: okay split up, thx for suggestion

Comment: I remember a story like this, did part of the plot revolve around their 'house-puter'?

Answer (score 5):

I was racking my brain all night and I believe this to be David Marusek's "**[Counting Heads](http://www.actusf.com/spip/Interview-David-Marusek-VO.html)**".  The novel had two distinct parts; the second was set 40 years after the first and is similar to what you describe above.  The group of people living together is the Charter in the novel. The guy on the roof is the main character Samson (formerly an affluent man, "seared" by the government for being damaged, hence he can't be touched).  The smaller character is Bogden (an adult taking drugs to remain a child).

Here's the best description I can find [online](http://voices.yahoo.com/characters-ideas-drive-counting-heads-david-370724.html).

Also, you posted an additional question around the same time.  That also might be this novel as it did feature classes of clones (named Fred, Jerry, etc) fighting unapproved non-clone-allowed behaviours.

[image]

Comment: Thank you both so much for answering this - indeed this is the book! (sorry for delayed thanks)  Too funny that it was the same book after all, totally different story lines - a wild read for sure!

Comment: PS I'm pleased to see there was a sequel "Mind Over Ship" !