# Seeking title of sci fi book with male police clones 'Jerrys'

Tags: story-identification

Lady is stuck in mansion, imprisoned in her mind perhaps, someone trying to gain control of her company or her spouse’s company for its IP? Side story involves police force made up of clones including one set named Jerrys, one in particular starts to go rogue as he becomes more self aware; he is married to another clone a lady who is meant to be a ‘comforter’ and whose life suddenly has purpose now that she has been assigned to help the lady in the mansion. Big firefight at the end. Maybe an underground private train too? Nanotechology including weapons that can transform themselves (+ repair)

Thanks!

Comment: For some reason the description makes me want to say it's Asimov, but right now I can't say which story.

Comment: See my answer here (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/38987/7896) to your other recent question.  I think it's the same book.

Comment: Mark is right. I've found an interview where the author discusses clones named "jerry" in his book Counting Heads; http://www.actusf.com/spip/Interview-David-Marusek-VO.html you may have become confused into thinking it's two different books because it's split into two separate 'acts'

Answer (score 5):

Per Mark's answer to your [other question here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38889/seeking-title-of-sci-fi-book-with-bee-camera-global-paparazzi/38987#38987), it seems likely that *both* books are in fact the *same* book;

> I believe this to be David Marusek's "**[Counting Heads](http://www.actusf.com/spip/Interview-David-Marusek-VO.html)**".  The
>   novel had two distinct parts; the second was set 40 years after the
>   first and is similar to what you describe above.  The group of people
>   living together is the Charter in the novel. The guy on the roof is
>   the main character Samson (formerly an affluent man, "seared" by the
>   government for being damaged, hence he can't be touched).  The smaller
>   character is Bogden (an adult taking drugs to remain a child).
>
> Here's the best description I can find [online](http://voices.yahoo.com/characters-ideas-drive-counting-heads-david-370724.html).

The novel feature various classes of clones (named Fred, **Jerry**, etc) fighting unapproved non-clone-allowed behaviours.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for answering this - indeed this is the book! (sorry for delayed thanks)  Too funny that it was the same book after all, totally different story lines - a wild read for sure!

Comment: PS I'm pleased to see there was a sequel "Mind Over Ship" !

Comment: @Jimmy - Don't forget to upvote and press the "accepted" button on the left-hand side of the answer.